# get last line of file and write new record on it

Tags: c++

i have a c++ program to get last line data of issuance.csv file(has id , date,time) and write new record on it
but when i try to write new data(like id,time,date) on it ,save blank line without data on issuance.csv file ,what should i do??

```
#define DEFAULT_ID "2000"
#define ISSUE_FILE_ADDRESS "/home/pi/file/issuance.csv"

int WriteNewRecord(string NewID, string NewCustomerID, string NewIssueDate)
{
    fstream FileStream;
    FileStream.open(ISSUE_FILE_ADDRESS, fstream::app | fstream::out);//Just for write into file
    if(!FileStream.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File Open Error1" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    FileStream << NewID << "," << NewCustomerID << "," << NewIssueDate  << endl;//Just for write into file
    FileStream.close();
    return 0;
}
int GetLastData(string& LastID, string& LastCustomerID, string& LastDate, string& LastTime)
{
    fstream FileStream;
    FileStream.open(ISSUE_FILE_ADDRESS, fstream::in);
    if(!FileStream.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File Open Error2" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    string Line;
    int Indices[3];
    getline(FileStream, Line);
    if(Line.length())
    {
        do {
            Indices[0] = Line.find(",");
            Indices[1] = Line.find(",", Indices[0] + 1);
            Indices[2] = Line.find(",", Indices[1] + 1);

            LastID = Line.substr(0, Indices[0]);
            LastCustomerID = Line.substr(Indices[0] + 1, Indices[1] - Indices[0] - 1);
            LastDate = Line.substr(Indices[1] + 1, Indices[2] - Indices[1] - 1);
            LastTime = Line.substr(Indices[2] + 1, Line.length() - Indices[2] - 1);
            getline(FileStream, Line);

        } while (Line.length());
    }
    else
        LastID = DEFAULT_ID;

    FileStream.close();
    return 0;
}
int time(){
     time_t currentTime;
      struct tm *localTime;

      time( &currentTime );                   // Get the current time
      localTime = localtime( &currentTime );  // Convert the current time to the local time

      int Day    = localTime->tm_mday;
      int Month  = localTime->tm_mon + 1;
      int Year   = localTime->tm_year + 1900;
      int Hour   = localTime->tm_hour;
      int Min    = localTime->tm_min;
      int Sec    = localTime->tm_sec;
      cout  << Day << "/" << Month << "/" << Year << ", "<< Hour << ":" << Min << ":" << Sec<<endl;
      //std::cout  << std::endl;

      return (currentTime);
}


int main()
{
    string ID,CustomerID,Date,Time;
    if(!GetLastData(ID, CustomerID, Date,Time))
    {
        cout << ID << " " << CustomerID << " " << Date << " " << Time << endl;
        //Issuance Operation...
        //...
        //...
//      if(!WriteNewRecord("2008", "100000", "4/29/2015" , "10:55:15"))//Example for test
         string NewID,NewCustomerID,NewIssueDate;
    if(!WriteNewRecord(NewID, NewCustomerID, NewIssueDate))
        {
        unsigned int new_id = atoi(ID.c_str()) + 1;
        char tmp[5];
        sprintf(tmp, "%d", new_id);
        NewID = string(tmp);
        tmp[4] = 0;
        NewCustomerID=CustomerID;
        char write[4];
           unsigned int new_date=time();
            memcpy(write,&new_date,2);
            //cout << write << endl;
            sscanf ( NewIssueDate.c_str(), "%d", &new_date );

                      cout<< NewIssueDate<<"," << NewCustomerID<<","<< NewID <<endl;

            //cout << NewIssueDate<<endl;

            return 0;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To get the last line in a text file, I would do something like this: `std::string last_line, current_line; while (std::getline(FileStream, current_line)) { last_line = current_line; }` After the loop `last_line` will be the last line read. And if you put the string into a [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) you can actually use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to parse it (call `std::getline` with `','` as separator).

Comment: You're declaring `string NewID,NewCustomerID,NewIssueDate, NewIssueTime;`, doing *nothing* with them, then immediately passing them to `WriteNewRecord`. So perhaps fix that *first* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your code, you do

```
string NewID,NewCustomerID,NewIssueDate, NewIssueTime;
if(!WriteNewRecord(NewID, NewCustomerID, NewIssueDate))
{
    // Initialize variable but don't write them to the file
}
```

When you declare the `std::string` variables, they are initialized to be empty, so writing them to a file will write nothing. You *then* initialize the variables, after you write them to the file.

Comment: i cant understand can you get an example??

Comment: @NastaranMyri Think a little, what is the value of, for example, the `NewID` variable just when you have declared it? Nothing, it's empty. What will happen when you write an empty string to a file? Nothing will be written.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `FileStream.seekp (std::ios::end);` before writing

Comment: before writing means where??

Comment: Ah... after seeing the other answer I may have misunderstood your prob. you done even get the commas?